# Uml diagram Tomcat and Axis2

Tags: tomcat, uml, apache-axis, diagram

I have no idea how to create a deployment diagram for a client (android) and server (I have a `.aar` file that is deployed inside the `axis2` directory; and axis2 deployed inside `Tomcat`). They use `SOAP` to communicate.

I've tried this and I don't know if is ok:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay. Don't get too caught up with it UML diagrams. They should be taken as loose guidelines. Ultimately, you want people to understand, so a concise diagram is better than one that fulfills every little nitty gritty requirement of UML.